# JQuery .post() return html into table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .post

I have a form with two input boxes.  Song and Artist.  When the search button is pressed, it uses the JQuery function of `.post()` to post the data to a PHP page and return results back to the page.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $("#submitSearch").bind("click", function() {
            var songTitle = $("#song").val();
            var artistName = $("#artist").val();

            $.post("getSearchResults.php", {
                artist: artistName, 
                song: songTitle
            },
            function( data, status ) {
                $("#searchResults tbody").last().append( data );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The goal is to put the results into the `<tbody>` of the "searchResults" table.

```
<table id="searchResults">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Album</th>
            <th>Add To List</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, it doesn't seem to be inserting the results into the table.

It's not until I put an `alert()` message in the Javascript Code that it shows it.

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $("#submitSearch").bind("click", function() {
            var songTitle = $("#song").val();
            var artistName = $("#artist").val();

            $.post("getSearchResults.php", {
                artist: artistName, 
                song: songTitle
            },
            function( data, status ) {
                $("#searchResults tbody").last().append( data );
            });

            alert("test");

        });
    });
</script>
```

When I dismiss the "test" alert, it puts the results into the table and very quickly they disappear.

What am I missing here? Please help me! I am stumped.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any other javascript that references `#searchResults`?

Comment: My blind guess would be : some other code interfere with your table. Do you have other javascript code that mess with the table ?

Comment: No, there is only one place in the JS code that references `$("#searchResults")` and thats shown above.

Comment: I find it odd how it shows the results when i put an `alert()` into the code. seems like i need something like `on success` then... show it.

Comment: I think Archer is probably correct. The alert delays the page refresh long enough for the ajax call to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $("#submitSearch").bind("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var songTitle = $("#song").val();
            var artistName = $("#artist").val();

            $.post("getSearchResults.php", {
                artist: artistName, 
                song: songTitle
            },
            function( data, status ) {
                $("#searchResults tbody").last().append( data );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I added an event parameter to the click function, and `e.preventDefault()`.  this stops the submit actually taking place, which is reloading your page.  Also, depending on which version of jQuery you are using you may want to use `on()` instead of `bind()`.  (It's exactly the same syntax as above.)

Comment: Yes, that worked.  Thank you very much for your help. That makes sense now.  The text boxes and input button are inside a `<form>` tag, so it does make sense.

Comment: Archer - Accepted answer. Thanks, I knew it had to be something simple! Thankful for a community of other developers like you. Make it a great day!