# Use jQuery to update URL with value from checkboxes and keep checked after refresh

Tags: php, jquery

I have found a very nice jQuery script that helps me to get values from checkboxes sent to the URL as an array. This works perfectly, but I need the page to refresh after each selection, but by doing this, the checkboxes uncheck in Google Chrome (works fine in FF). The URL keeps fine, but the checkboxes all uncheck.

Is there any way in jQuery to keep the checked checkboxes checked after a refresh? Normally for me, when wanting a checkbox to be checked after a post or refresh, I can use an if-statement within the checkbox that i.e. says if($_GET[selected] == $value){ echo "checked"; }

You can test the code here: http://mazey.dk/bato/temp.php

The code looks like this:

```
<?
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Konfigurator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    font-family: Tahoma, "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

     <div class="flowers">
     <?
    $hent_access  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bato_produkter WHERE typen = 2");
    while($hent_access_data = mysql_fetch_array($hent_access)){
    $erstat2 = str_replace('BATO','bata',$hent_access_data[navn]);
    ?>
    <div class="flowers">

    <label>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
  <tr>
    <td><img src="images/<?=$hent_access_data[vnr]?>.jpg" width="150" class="apply_image" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="product_list_header"><?=$erstat2?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td  class="product_list_header">kr. <?=$hent_access_data[pris]?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td  class="product_list_header"><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?=$hent_access_data[vnr]?>" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</label>
    </div>
    <?
    }
    ?>
    </div>

<script>
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e){
var data = [],
loc = $('<a>', {href:window.location})[0];
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i){
if(this.checked){
data.push(this.name+'='+this.value);
}
});
data = data.join('&');
$.post('<?=$actual_link?>', data);
if(history.pushState){
history.pushState(null, null, loc.pathname+'?cart=<?=$_GET[cart]?>&'+data);
location.reload();
}

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

---- EDIT ----

After reading the comments and researching for a while, I am now trying to do it all through jQuery and AJAX calls, as I can read would be the most correct to do (and I get to learn something entirely new). So this is what I've got so far:

```
<form action="" method="post">

     <?
    $hent_access  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bato_produkter WHERE typen = 2");
    while($hent_access_data = mysql_fetch_array($hent_access)){
        $erstat2 = str_replace('BATO','bata',$hent_access_data[navn]);
    ?>

    <label>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
  <tr>
    <td><img src="images/<?=$hent_access_data[vnr]?>.jpg" width="150" class="apply_image" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="product_list_header"><?=$erstat2?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td  class="product_list_header">kr. <?=$hent_access_data[pris]?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td  class="product_list_header"><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?=$hent_access_data[vnr]?>" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</label>
    <?
    }
    ?>
   </form>

<script>
var data = $("form").serialize(); 
var checked = []

$("input[name='selected[]']:checked").each(function ()
{ 
$.ajax({
        url: "hello.php", 
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        data: data, 
        success: function(data){ 
            alert(data) 
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

The hello.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
include('../settings.inc.php');

    foreach ($_POST[selected] as $value) {
    $list_valg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bato_produkter WHERE vnr = '$value'");
    $list_valg_data = mysql_fetch_array($list_valg);
    $pris += $list_valg_data[pris]; 
    $space_used += $list_valg_data[funktion];
    }

echo $pris." - Space used ".$space_used."<br/>Total Space available ".$vogn_space;

?>
```

Now I've gotten the alert to show me the result, but only when I refresh the page manually (CTRL+R), and furthermore it loads an alert-box for every checkbox checked.

What I am trying to accomplish right now, is for the alert box to show the results from hello.php when checking a checkbox, but only once with all the checkboxes accumulated.

----- EDIT -----

Everything now works like I wanted it to, so that's absolutely perfect!
As an extension I have one more thing:
If you look at the site - http://mazey.dk/bato/temp.php

When you have picked the first item with the radio button the checkboxes show. When you check a checkbox you can see in the upper left hand corner the status of the selection and also the space availible. For the products with the checkboxes they all require a certain amount of space. Visually it is displayed in the last part of the text (1/3, 2/3 or 1/1) but it is also stored in a table row for every product (stored as integers; 1,2,3).

Can you lead me on the way in how to accomplish the products + checkboxes to be hidden if the products space exceeds the space available?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: In HTML5 you can use History.pushState() to change the url without leaving the page. Note the capital H. No need for the page to change if you can ajax and change the url. For backwards compatibility, use History.js. https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

Comment: True, but I need the page to reload for some PHP - as you can see, the script contains pushState which works fine, but I need the checkboxes to stay checked on refresh too.

Comment: Why do you need to refresh the page? The PHP can all be done in an ajax call, the data returned in json, and the info updated accordingly with js or jQuery. And why even use pushState() if you are loading a page? Just load the page with window.location. Its the same thing. If you want your checkboxes to stay checked, you will need to pass something to the url for a GET or post data which will be available in POST. Or just use ajax

Comment: Interesting @zgr024 - I need the values from the URL to make a PHP loop that retrieves the column id's in a table for all in all to show images and accumulate prices. If that can be done "on-the-fly" without refresh would be absolutely cool. Can you lead me on the way?

Comment: @MazeyMazey http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: You are already half way there. Your $.post just needs a callback to get whatever the response is. `$.post(url,data,function(json) {console.log(json)},'json');`

Comment: Alternatively you can return html and place that in a spot on your page... `$.post(url,data,function(html) { $("#somediv").html(html); });`

Comment: See this post for some help with what you need... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007165/jquery-post-return-html-into-table

Comment: jQuery, json is very new to me, so therefore I went with the refresh, because I am more confident with plain PHP - but I will try and read up on the json / jQuery and try to make something out of it, even though right now it does seem pretty crazy to accomplish and handle :-D

Comment: Okay @zgr024 - I will try to look at that. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @zgr024 I have looked at the link and afterwards researched a bit on how to post from jQuery directly to PHP/MySQL - I have updated my question and added the code as far as I've gotten. I feel like I'm on the right track (or maybe I'm not). Maybe you could take a look at it? Thanks. :-)

Comment: I will try to help you when i get back in front of my computer. On mobile at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating through the selected boxes on page load instead of on the change event.
You have 2 options, a submit button or post every time a checkbox is clicked.

You mentioned you wanted to wait until all checkboxes are done being checked, but the script will never know that the user is done clicking checkboxes unless you have a submit button. However, in this case you don't want a submit button according to your question.

The following will post the selected values upon clicking the checkboxes on or off. The event will be fired each time a checkbox is manipulated and your returned data can be used to manipulate a table or it can return HTML. In this example its returning the data as HTML from hello.php which then places that response in a div element with the id of "result"

```
<form action="" method="post">

    **** ADDED FOR NEW QUESTION ****
    <input type="hidden" id="totalSpaces" value="12"> 

<?
    $hent_access  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bato_produkter WHERE typen = 2");
    while($hent_access_data = mysql_fetch_array($hent_access)) {
        $erstat2 = str_replace('BATO','bata',$hent_access_data[navn]);
?>

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
        <tr>
            <td><img src="images/<?=$hent_access_data[vnr]?>.jpg" width="150" class="apply_image" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="product_list_header"><?=$erstat2?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="product_list_header">kr. <?=$hent_access_data[pris]?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            *** EDITED FOR NEW QUESTION ***
            <td class="product_list_header"><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?=$hent_access_data[vnr]?>" data-spaces="<?=$hent_access_data['pris']?>" /></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
<?
    }
?>


</form>
<div id="result"></div>   

<script>
    *** ADDED FOR NEW QUESTION *** 
    var totalSpaces = $('#totalSpaces').val();
    var usedSpaces = 0;

    // triggered when user clicks a checkbox
    $('input[name="selected[]"]').on('change',function () { 


        *** ADDED FOR NEW QUESTION ***
        currentSpaces = parseInt($(this).data('spaces');

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) usedSpaces += currentSpaces;
        else usedSpaces -= currentSpaces;

        if (usedSpaces > totalSpaces) {
            alert('Will not fit');
            return false;
        }           


        // grabs the selected checkbox values
        var data = $("form").serialize(); 


        // Sends the data via POST to hello.php
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "hello.php", 
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'html',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function(data) { 

                *** ADDED FOR NEW QUESTION ***
                if (usedSpaces == totalSpaces) {
                    alert ('All spaces used');
                    $('input[name="selected[]"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled',true);
                }
                else {
                    $('input[name="selected[]"]').prop('disabled',false);
                }
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        }); 
    });

</script>
```

Please see the edits marked ADDED or EDITED

Comment: Thank you so much @zgr024 - I will try this when I get back to my computer. I am beginning to see the structure in what you're explaining and showing, so I am very keen on getting more familiar with this. I will test later - thanks again.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect! It works like a charm, and I do feel better at seeing the logic in jQuery :-) I'll accept your answer and really I appreciate what you have helped me with. I have a question more though, but this has to do with me wanting the checkboxes to be hidden if they exceed a certain size (which I have stored in a variable in the hello.php file). Would the right thing here be to post a new question?... Thanks again!

Comment: Actually better to ask a new question or try it yourself first. But place the limit on the page with the checkboxes and not in the php. You can do this with a hidden field in the form and place the numbers in a data attribute. Then add them up in the change event.

Comment: Great @zgr024 - I have edited my post, so the last part contains the last question for you - please let me know if you have any questions as it was a bit hard for me to explain :-)

Comment: Please see the edits I've made to the answer. You should not use the post to determine what was used vs available. I would consider not using the post at all in fact because you can manipulate the html without the PHP and the new query by placing everything you need in data attributes instead

Comment: Wuau @zgr024 - you're really really awesome at this. What a help, but I must confess that now I have trouble seeing the logic in the scripts (so I have to read up on this). I can see what you do with the hidden form-field and the data-spaces on the checkboxes, but the jQuery validation are a more complex for me to understand, but it works. I'm thinking however that if I put each product with the checkbox inside a DIV with a unique id, maybe the entire product could be hidden when the usedSpaces - totalSpaces are smaller than the products data-spaces instead of the alerts? I'm thinking :-)

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this:

`<div id="<?=$hent_access_data[vnr]?>">
PRODUCT-DATA + Checkbox
</div>
<script>
spacesLeft = usedSpaces - totalSpaces;
if (currentSpaces > spacesLeft) {
$( "#DIV_ID" ).hide();
}</script>`

Comment: I think I'm getting close, but need the last push to succeed (perhaps) :-)   
`spacesLeft = totalSpaces - usedSpaces;
  
if ($('input[name="selected[]"]').data('spaces') > spacesLeft) { 
    $( "#DIV_ID" ).hide();
    }else{
    $( "#DIV_ID" ).show();
    }`

Comment: I don't think you want to hide it. What if the user changes their mind about a tool set. Or isn't sure. I would just disable and have a button "done" that then hides it

Comment: Maybe you're right - But then maybe instead of hiding it, the div could be disabled, so it dimms down. I would like to make it easier to see which can be chosen and what can't - also "on the fly" so that if there's only 2 spaces left, the 3-space products dimm/hides "on the fly" instead of being able to click them, and then be told that it doesn't fit. So let's say I want to dimm instead of hiding - how close am I with the script I have started? :-)

Comment: Dimming so to speak, requires another div to act as an overlay. The div would have a background color and opacity of .6 or .7 and be hidden until you want to display it. It's a little more complex and not necessarily the way i would go about it. Overlays also prevent the user from clicking the boxes. They still need to be able to undo their selections. You're better off with what i suggested and perhaps a message that states that it's full instead of the alert. If you have more you want to do with this, post a new question to allow someone else to gain rep. There are a lot of smart people here

Comment: Thanks a lot @zgr024 - I really appreciate the big effort you have put into this! You have been a very big help.